# update-alternatives python configuration is not working as per the current choice

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

As you find my terminal commands and output below, there are two issues I am facing.

```
    There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).
    
      Selection    Path                 Priority   Status
    ------------------------------------------------------------
      0            /usr/bin/python3.11   10        auto mode
      1            /usr/bin/python3.11   10        manual mode
    * 2            /usr/bin/python3.7    0         manual mode
    
    Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 
    update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/bin/python3.7 because link group python is broken
    pavan@mars:~$ python --version
    Python 3.11.0
    pavan@mars:~$ virt-manager 
    bash: /usr/bin/virt-manager: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
    pavan@mars:~$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 0
```

1. Though current choice is set to python3.7, the python command still referring to 3.11 version
2. But then running any python based "apps" are failing. However, if I run .py scripts they are running fine.

Appreciate the help! Thanks.

### Update:

````
pavan@mars:/usr/bin$ ls -la /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Dec  2 20:58 /usr/bin/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.11
pavan@mars:/usr/bin$ virt-manager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virt-manager", line 6, in <module>
    from virtManager import virtmanager
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/virtmanager.py", line 13, in <module>
    import gi
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized module 'gi' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)```
````

Comment: The error message is talking about `/usr/bin/python3` but you're `update-alternates`ing `python`..? What does `ls -la /usr/bin/python3` say?

Comment: `$ ls -la /usr/bin/python3

ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/python3': No such file or directory`

Comment: What does `type -a python` output? What does `head -n 1 $(type -p virt-manager)` output?

Comment: ```$ type -a python
python is aliased to `python3'
python is /usr/bin/python
python is /bin/python


$ head -n 1 $(type -p virt-manager)
#!/usr/bin/python3
```